# sequential setState calls not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am creating a component with an animation that occurs with a css class toggle. Sandbox of the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjpz5wkq6q).

The css class is applied conditionaly against the `transitioned` field, so we should get an animation when the `transtioned` field goes form `false` to `true`.

Problem:

The animation doesn't happen in the case where the state if modified like this :

```
animateWithoutST = () => {
    this.setState({transitioned: false}, 
    () => this.setState({transitioned: true}))
  }
```

But it works if it the second `setState` is called within a `setTimeout` callback like this:

```
 animateWithST = () => {
    this.setState({ transitioned: false },
    () => {
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ transitioned: true }))
    }
    )
  }
```

Why isn't `animateWithoutST` working as expected although my component is rendering in the right order ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looked definitely bizarre and I had to dig into it until I understood what is happening.

So, yeah without the `setTimeout` it doesn't work, not even in the `componentDidUpdate` method and there is an explanation: you are changing the state, and it is updated, and render is called twice BUT because of browser optimization we don't see the animation happening: ***"browsers are not re-rendering stuff that changed in the same animation frame"***.

When you use the `setTimeout` you are forcing the 2nd state update to go into the next animation frame and voila you see the animation. Even with the current timeout value set to 0, it might not work on some browsers, but if you set the value to > 16ms aprox, it prob will work always (you need a value greater than an animation frame).

You can also use `requestAnimationFrame`, twice to assure your both state updates fall into different animation frames, check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/883w3qqj98).

I found all this info in this [article](https://stanko.github.io/react-rerender-in-component-did-mount/), check it because it is extremely well explained. Does now make sense to you?

Comment: Using `requestAnimationFrame` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `componentDidUpdate` instead:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(!this.state.transitioned) {
        this.setState({
            transitioned: true
        });
    }
}
```

This makes sure that your second `setState` gets called AFTER the component has updated.

Answer (score -2):

`setState` is asyncronous which means calls do not happen back to back. So multiple calls to setstate might not happen as you expect them to. Read [this](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3) to know more about `setstate()`

Comment: setState is async but the guy is already trying to setState again after first one finishes, so that's not the case why it's failing.